# Ayuda con setProxy (const QString & proxyJid) en QT

Tags: c++, qt

Hola necesito incluir a mi XMPP un proxy pero tengo varias cuestion se me pide el Jid del SOCKS5 que vaya utilizar que es esto?
Tendría que hacer lo siguiente:

```
manager = new QXmppTransferManager;
manager->setProxy(const QString & proxyJid);
```

Fuente:
http://doc.qxmpp.org/qxmpp-0.7.5/classQXmppTransferManager.html#ad7d0f0496c85b85b448010d8a3c86d23

Cualquier ayuda me vendría para poder configurar my proxy en xmpp con transferencia de archivos ya que tengo un chat y el firewall pues cuando mando archivos con el chat es un martirio...